# How to collect Prometheus metric information from a Spring Boot Singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, prometheus

I'd like to use Prometheus to monitor my Java Spring-Boot application.  I have been able to collect Prometheus metrics successfully when declaring a Prometheus metric (Summary in this example), and using it, inside of the same class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application{

    /* Prometheus Metric*/
    private static final Summary summary = Summary.build()
                         .name("api_latency")
                         .help("elapsed time in call to api")
                         .register();

    /* Prometheus Metric*/
    private static SimpleTimer timer;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void home(){

        timer = new SimpleTimer();
        //a call to an API goes here
        summary.observe(timer.elapsedSeconds());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But if I move the Prometheus `Summary` declaration out of the `@SpringBootApplication` class, and into a class annotated with `@Component`, Prometheus can no longer seem to detect my `Summary` metric.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application{

    /*Code that invokes SomeClass goes here.*/

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


@Component
public class SomeClass {

    /* Prometheus Metric*/
    private static final Summary summary = Summary.build()
                         .name("api_latency")
                         .help("elapsed time in call to api")
                         .register();

    /* Prometheus Metric*/
    private static SimpleTimer timer;

    .
    .
    .

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduled.job.time}")
    public void run(){

        timer = new SimpleTimer();
        //an API call goes here
        summary.observe(timer.elapsedSeconds())
    }
}
```

How do I get Prometheus to detect my `Summary` metric data from within a singleton?

Answer (score -1):

If your `Someclass.java` is not in the same package or sub-package as `Application.java`, spring doesn't scan it by default.

You may need to explicitly call out the class you'd like to scan

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses={SomeClass.class})
@EnableScheduling
public class Application { 
}
```